How to perform additional calculations for items displayed on the current page in Yii2 ArrayDataProvider?
I am creating an ArrayDataProvider like this:
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $data,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'quantity',
        ],
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'quantity' => SORT_DESC,
        ]
    ],
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10
    ]
]);

Let's assume that the $data array contains 1000 elements. I want to perform resource-intensive calculations, but doing them for all 1000 elements is too slow. So, I would like to apply these calculations only to the items displayed on the current page, in this case, for the first 10 elements.
To achieve this, I added the following code:
$allModels = $dataProvider->getModels();

foreach ($allModels as &$model) {
    // Some complex calculations with value assignment
    $model['value'] = 123;
}

However, when I pass $dataProvider to GridView, the displayed elements on the page do not contain the value key that I previously created. The same issue occurs if I immediately output $dataProvider->getModels() after processing.
How can I perform additional calculations for ArrayDataProvider only for the items displayed on the current page?

The getModels method of ArrayDataProvider returns an array of the data models in the current page, not a reference to them. So your calculations don't affect the original data models.
But you could do the calculations in GridView directly, like this:
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => 'value',
            'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                //... $result = do the calculations
                return $result;
            }
        ],
    ],
]);



It might be better to use value callback instead of content callback. That way the format setting of column can apply to calculation result.
